# How to call a variable for hostlist from a file Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i would like to know about calling the variable in bash.

I have file called `/home/user/linux_hosts` where i have hostname's are there like:

```
host001
host002
host003
host004
```

Below is what i am running.

```
#!/bin/bash

    ping_hostList="$(< /home/user/linux_hosts)"
    
    for line in ${ping_hostList}
    do
        pingHost -c2 "${line}" 
    done
```

So, in the above script i have declared a variable `ping_hostList` and it has a file which contains the hostnames. As you see i am using `<` sign to get the hostnames from a file and then calling that variable in a script which works but i'm looking what will be the best approach to call of hostnames from a file in a bash script.

Any trick and pure bash thing will be highly appreaciated.

I know this could be simple as:

```
#!/bin/bash

    
    for line in $(cat /home/user/linux_hosts)
    do
        pingHost -c2 "${line}" 
    done
```

Comment: See [How can I read a file line-by-line?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Answer (score 4):

Using a `while` loop with the `read` builtin is usually the canonical way here:

```
while read -r host; do
    pingHost -c2 "$host";
done < linux_hosts
```

If you want to disable field splitting, set `IFS` to an empty value: `while IFS= read -r host`.

Or you might prefer [`xargs`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xargs.html):

```
< linux_hosts xargs -L1 pingHost -c2
```

Comment: knittl, thnks for the answer , however i am little worried about using  this redirection `<` , Is there better of using it and avoid this.

Comment: Why would you be worried about redirecting a file to standard input? Your suggestion in the question even redirects, albeit a bit "hidden" (`$(<file)`). `<` is the best way (since you are asking for a "better" way). You could use `cat` with a pipe, but that's the worse way (because it requires on additional process to be started)

Comment: okay .. i was thinking loud and overshooting my expectation if there is diffrent way of doing this `<` , absolutely doing cat with a pipe but extra cost of opening a new socket with a pipe.

Comment: @user294110 Yes, there is a different way: either IO redirect or cat + pipe. I don't understand the last part of your sentence.